# Is $T$ considered a constant after the integration?

Tags: integration, physics, distribution-theory

I have integrated a distribution function (for sterile neutrinos), of a form similar to:

$$\left( \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial T}\right)_{E/T}= ..... \tag{1}$$

Meaning that throughout the integration $E/T$ should be treated as a constant.  Where $E$ signifies momentum and $T$, temperature.

At the end of the integration my answer is of the form:

$$f_s = \frac{E}{T} x $$

where $x$ is some variable.

I am trying to plot this in terms of $T$ and $x$ but I am not sure of what to do because I have the following doubt:

**Is $E/T$ still seen as a constant even after the integration has been done?**

**If the ratio is still a constant, can I  consider $T$ to be a variable and to therefore plot $f_s /T$?**

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is not a constant, but $E/T$ is. So you have $f_s = kx,$ where $k=E/T.$ This gives $f_s/T = kx/T.$

Comment: This means, that it would still be possible for me to plot a graph in which T is seen as a variable, right?

Comment: @user7077252. As I understand it, yes.